# API question - How to REST request with Python

Tags: python, json, rest, api

I'm making an API REST request using Python. And I encountered the following html result that says "Service - Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service"

How can I fix this issue?

Note: This API can help determine whether an individual address is up to date by inputting individual address, first name, last name, etc.

**Python query**

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover/'
payload = {'t': '1353', 'id': 'sw38hs47u', 'jobid': '1', 'act': 'NCOA, CCOA', 'cols': 'TransmissionResults,TransmissionReference, Version, TotalRecords,CASSReportLink,NCOAReportLink,Records,AddressExtras,AddressKey,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressTypeCode,BaseMelissaAddressKey,CarrierRoute,City,CityAbbreviation,CompanyName,CountryCode,CountryName,DeliveryIndicator,DeliveryPointCheckDigit,DeliveryPointCode,MelissaAddressKey,MoveEffectiveDate,MoveTypeCode,PostalCode,RecordID,Results,State,StateName,Urbanization', 'opt': 'ProcessingType: Standard', 'List': 'test', 'full': 'PATEL MANISH', 'first':'MANISH','last':'PATEL', 'a1':'1600 S 5TH ST', 'a2':'1600 S 5TH ST', 'city':'Austin', 'state': 'TX', 'postal': '78704', 'ctry': 'USA'}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

print (response.text)
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p xmlns="">Endpoint not found. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

Comment: The message is telling us that the endpoint doesn't like the format of your request. Maybe log it to the console and compare with the examples in the help page. (Assuming that the API for requests is valid, which is in question given the other comments.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/` at the end of the url:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover' # <<<
payload = {'t': '1353', 'id': 'sw38hs47u', 'jobid': '1', ...}
response = requests.get(
    url, params=payload,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'} # Using JSON here for readability in the response
)

print (response.text)
```

Output:

```
{
    "CASSReportLink": "",
    "NCOAReportLink": "",
    "Records": [],
    "TotalRecords": "",
    "TransmissionReference": "1353",
    "TransmissionResults": "SE20",
    "Version": "4.0.4.48"
}
```